# npm global install not recognized (gulp)

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to use gulp for the first time.

Following instructions online, I installed it globally as well as locally, but I still get the
`'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command[...]` error. When using PowerShell instead of cmd the error is `the term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file[...]`

I've tried:

- installing gulp-cli in addition to gulp
- adding / changing PATH variables
- restarting my PC
- running `npm install -g npm@latest` to make sure npm is up-to-date

I'm stumped. On top of all that, I have other npm packages installed globally that work fine.

Edit: I fixed this by adding npm to my PATH environment variable. I had been adding it to NODE_PATH, which doesn't work for CLI use.

Answer (score 0):

"Global install" with the `-g` flag basically means you install the command provided with the package.

To globally install gulp:

```sh
npm install gulp -g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the gulp script in the package.json file and run the gulp command using npm.

Ex:

- gulp task name : helloTest
- Add below code in package.json:

> ```
>  "scripts": {
>      
>         "helloTest": "gulp helloTest",
>   }
> ```

And now type below command in terminal:

> npm run helloTest